# Create a windows Driver

Tags: windows, driver, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create a driver for CSR-V4.0 (CSR8510). My aim is to detect a BLE-beacon for my application. Now I am detecting the beacons using [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) and [zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/). I am trying to remove the nodejs dependency from my project. I have a very little knowledge about driver development. I tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-driver) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/wdf/index?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Can anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you install `visual studio` at your system and then the compatible WDK(WDK10 for VS2015) for it.

After that you just download the sample drivers provided by microsoft from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples)

OR [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/samples/index.). 
Open up the  bluetooth sample driver project modify the code according to your requirements and select your platform and the target OS and build it that's it.